# Making an ADB batch [ADB shell stopping issue]

Tags: android, shell, adb

This is my idea of what I want to do, simply execute the following commands but instead right after the line "adb shell" it stops, no other command can be triggered, whatever it is.

```
    adb connect 192.168.1.101:5555 

    adb shell
    su 
    rm /data/system/locksettings.db 
    rm /data/system/locksettings.db-wal 
    rm /data/system/locksettings.db-shm 
    PAUSE

    reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

`adb shell` command alone with out any extra parameters starts the shell in the *interactive* mode. Meaning it just sits there waiting for user input indefinitely. Your script never gets past that line.

What you really want is:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.101:5555 

adb shell su 0 rm /data/system/locksettings.db 
adb shell su 0 rm /data/system/locksettings.db-wal 
adb shell su 0 rm /data/system/locksettings.db-shm 

PAUSE

adb reboot
```

Comment: Thank you but now it says "unable to connect to :5555". I tried "su 1" just in case but that seems to stop super user.

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I've done some more things. It works now, thank you.