# windows batch script not execute next line after "adb shell"

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

windows batch script:

```
adb shell
echo hello
```

why does the next line `echo hello` not execute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26224524/1778421

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next line in a batch script executes after the previous command `adb shell` has finished.

`adb shell` starts an interactive shell and it finishes only after you exit the shell.

Assuming you want to execute `echo hello` in the adb shell, put them on the same line:

```
adb shell echo hello
```

In this form, `adb shell` doesn't start an interactive shell but operates in batch mode, running the command and then exiting.

---

> any method can force next command execute even the pre command not finished ?

Use `start` to launch a program in the background, e.g.

```
start /b adb shell
echo hello
```

Comment: any method can force next command execute even the pre command not finished ?

Comment: My purpose is entering android shell and execute android shell command

Comment: Use the `adb shell echo hello` then.