# adb shell command from batch file

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have a .bat file that runs script for testing an app and printing the log to file i have all the commands i tested them manually.

Problem:
after entering the command adb shell, the shell opens in the command prompt.   I wrote the next commands that are entered in the shell with root@generic
the commands aren't going through and it just waits at that spot.

what do i have to type in front of the commands to make them appear

example of what i have

```
cd directory of sdk
adb
adb shell
am instrumentation ... (this is the command that won't go through once the shell is open.
```

any help appreciated I've tried a few things with no success

Comment: None of those suggestions worked for me so made my own thread more specific to my issue and the first answer here worked

Comment: it a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26774721/1778421

Comment: Alex P. that was the same i couldn't locate that when searching thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following line in your batch file:

```
adb shell am instrumentation
```

that will connect to the shell on the Android device and run the `am` command.

Comment: That worked running on the same line didn't even open the shell interface but still ran the command.

Comment: would vote up but don't have enough points or whatever

Comment: @MichaelBurr, are you saying that you honestly thought that this is the first time this question has been asked here? If even 200K+ users keep answering duplicate questions - what can be expected from others?